# How to send BufferedImage using Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to send a BufferedImage in Spring Boot application.
I'm testing my APIs using Postman.
But it's returning :

```
{"accelerationPriority":0.5,"colorModel":{"transparency":1,"numComponents":3,"numColorComponents":3,"colorSpace":{"type":5,"numComponents":3,"profile":{"mediaWhitePoint":[0.95014954,1.0,1.0882568],"matrix":[[0.43585205,0.3853302,0.14302063],[0.22238159,0.717041,0.06059265],[0.013916016,0.09713745,0.71383667]],"majorVersion":2,"minorVersion":48,"profileClass":1,"colorSpaceType":5,"pcstype":0,"data":"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
```

Some data like this.

How can I solve this?

I want simply a jpg or png image on my client side, like this :

[image]

Comment: What do you expect? That *data* is your image as base64 string

Comment: i just want an image, that i can render in my client jpg format

Comment: Than decode it in your client

Comment: i can't can someone help me with it ?? @Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your codes, because you provided none. So I'll try to guess. It seems like you do not say to your client he will download an image.

Try adding this to your response header : `Content-type: image/jpeg`

I'll give some example code, but I can't promise it will work for you.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/myImage", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
```

If you want something more accurate, please provide your controller code.

Comment: i'm dumb, that was working.. the real problem was - i wasn't selecting the correct directory... instead of `pic/pic.png` i used `pic.png`.. path problem .. still thanks for helping ...